# What is the meaning of "the phrase "at this end"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What is the meaning of "at this end" in the sentence below?

> The other activity requiring at least 7 days notice is the drama workshop. Again, it is a question of organizing the staff ***at this end***.

Comment: Please tell us the source of the quote.  Also, think about your tags.  Putting both [american-english] and [british-english] doesn't make much sense.  Your question isn't about either dialect.  This is a  [phrase-meaning] question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

idiom: "at your end", "on our end"
https://www.myenglishteacher.eu/blog/on-your-end-or-at-your-end/

The idiom contrasts the locations at each 'end' of the communication: the speaker's end, and the listener's end.

In this context, they need 7-days to organize within their own group (*at this end*). It is a polite but firm way of saying they cannot shorten this preparation time.

Comment: Is it correct to say "It is a question of organizing the staff at my end"? Does it make any sense? if so, what is the difference between `It is a question of organizing the staff at my end` *and* `It is a question of organizing the staff at this end`

Comment: @Pankaj, "*this* end" suggests an office or company/org, but these are not strong nuances. The "*other* end" might be the job location, the destination (I assume, based on the context of the sentence). The main emphasis is they need time before they are ready to travel.

Comment: `for anyone who does not have a mobile phone, there are pay phones at the far end of the picnic area,` in this sentence can you tell me kindly that why for was used?

Comment: @Pankaj (This announcement is intended) "for anyone who doesn't have a mobile phone…"
Similar to opening with "To Whom it may concern…"

Comment: @Pankaj The phrases "`at my end`" and "`at this end`" almost always mean the same thing. Both of the following sentences have the same meaning: (1) `It is a question of organizing the staff at ` ***MY*** `end`" (2) `It is a question of organizing the staff at` ***this*** `end`

Comment: @Pankaj The main difference between "`the problem is at this end`" and "`the problem is at my end`" is that the phrase "`my end`" can be used to to say, "The problem is my fault" or "I am responsible for the problem." The phrase `this end` is used to say that someone near you is responsible for the issue, "`The problem is at this end`" means "I am at fault or my co-worker is at fault," without being clear about which person made the mistake.

Comment: can you please rephrase this sentence in simple speech? **I had like to use this tutorial as a feedback session, where you reflect on the experience of doing the project.**

Answer (score 1):

People often communicate using telephones where the speaker is in a different place from the listener.

---

The following are equivalent in meaning:

- "It is raining ***at this end***"
- "It is raining ***where I a located***"
- "It is raining ***where I am***"

The following are equivalent in meaning:

- "Things are going well ***at my end***. How are they going at **your end**?"
- "Either my life is going well or my project at work is going well. How are you doing?"

---

Imagine that when you use a telephone that there is a wire between you and someone else. The wire has two "***ends***". Where you are located is ***your*** end of the wire. Where the other person is located is the other ***end*** of the wire

---

When two businessmen belong to different organizations, then the following phrases even when the speaker and listener are standing in the same room together:

- at this end
- at my end
- at our end
- at my team's end

For example, we might have the following sentences:

> - "I know that you are ready, but we need another week at **our end**"
> - "The problem is on **your end**, not **our end**."

[image: picture of two different business/company department used to illustrate the concept of "my end"]

Comment: `for anyone who does not have a mobile phone, there are pay phones at the far end of the picnic area,` in this sentence can you tell me kindly that why for was used?

Comment: @Pankaj You have asked two different questions. (1) a question about a sentence whose beginning is "`for anyone who does not have `..." (2) a question about what the phrase "`at this end`" means. If you have more than one question about the English language, please post your questions separately. Press the "Ask Question" button at  [the English Learner's Stack Exchange](https://ell.stackexchange.com). Do not write any questions about English in the sections labeled "comments"

Comment: can you please rephrase this sentence in simple speech? **I had like to use this tutorial as a feedback session, where you reflect on the experience of doing the project.**

Answer (score 0):

The writer means 'at their own place of work'. If their organisation is asked to put on a workshop, they need seven days to arrange for the necessary staff to be available.
NB The sentence needs more punctuation to be correct English.